# Spark Column - Write to console

Tags: java, apache-spark

How can you output the contents of a `Column` to the console in Spark? For `DataFrame`s, `df.show()` is used, which doesn't work with `Column`s for whatever reason.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Column has no content. Select single column and show:

```
df.select(df.col("some")).show();
```

Comment: This is still for a dataframes's column. I'm interested in printing a Column. Like `Column toPrint = something; toPrint.show()` (which doesn't work).

Comment: There is nothing to print. Column doesn't contain data.

Comment: Ok, but I can do: `Column calc = df.("first").calc("something")` and then `df = df.withColumn("new", calc)`, so it has to contain SOMETHING...

Comment: It is description not data

Comment: Ok so if I fill a Column like I showed you before, there's no way to print it?